# Problem using DLC from another region

Tags: ps3, region-lock, uncharted-2

I bought Uncharted 2: GOTY last month and found that the DLC can only be redeemed on a US account. On the same PS3 I created another user with a US account and downloaded the contents, and it works fine.

But the problem is that the contents are not reflecting in my first profile, which is not a US account.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you try to add another account (that doesn't have any Uncharted data saved to it) and see if the DLC works then?

Comment: Send back your game and buy one from the region in which you live. While games themselves are region-free, the DLC usually isn't.

Comment: Oh man, I was thinking about importing the GotY for the DLC myself. This is disappointing to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with US DLC not working with a non US game is due to the game TitleID being different.
US games have a TitleID starting with BLUS{5 numbers} and EU has BLES{5 numbers}.
If you have for instance an EU game it stores gamedata and savegames in a folder starting with BLES00000 for instance. And the DLC will try to install under BLUS00000 so your game cannot see the DLC due to being installed in a different location.
There is no way to fix this without getting a copy from the appropriate region.
On the spine of the game boxes on the bottom is the TitleID for that copy.

List of most used titleID prefixes:
BCUS - sony REGION 1 game
BLUS- 3rd party REGION 1 game

BCES - sony REGION 2 or 4 game
BLES- 3rd party REGION 2 or 4 game

BCAS - sony REGION 3 game
BLAS - sony REGION 3 game

Make sure you get a copy from region 1 if you have US DLC.

Answer (score 0):

Send back your game and buy one from the region in which you live. While games themselves are region-free, the DLC usually isn't.

However, if you buy a "Game of the Year" edition which contains the DLC on-disc, you should be fine even if the game is imported. The problem arises when you have to purchase/download the DLC from a Playstation Network store that is not your local one.

Answer (score -1):

The DLC would be linked to the region account it was brought from. From my understanding, if you buy games off the US account and try to play them on your Europe one, it won't let you as it knows that account shouldn't have it, whereas if you buy a game on your Europe/US account, and use that content on the same region account, it works just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! The best answers here are ones with supporting evidence, ideally with a link to a page that explains in more detail (in this case, maybe something on Sony's site that talks about DLC and region restrictions). If you have such a link, or can find one, that could make this a solid answer.

Comment: That's incorrect. Most DLC on the PS3 can be used by any user on the console it was installed on. The only game I know that restricts DLC to the owning user only is Dungeon Siege III.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, apart from regional stuff. But like I said, from my understanding of it.